# Vue: Reset Arrays on select filters

Tags: vue.js

I have a form that has several select dropdowns which filter the data on the page. The data within each of the dropdown menus reduce as more selections are made by the user.

I can't seem to find a way to reset the select menus so that they show the all original options available from the dataset (I use Axios to pull the data) after they have performed the filtering.

I'm sure this should be easy but I can't get it to work. I can get the select menus to clear using the code below but it doesn't reset the array back to the original data number. Can anyone please help??

Method which performs the filter:

```
 Feeonchange: function() {
      let query = "";
      if (this.fee !== "") {
        query = this.uniqueFees;
      } else {
        query = "!showall";
      }
      this.query(query);
    },
```

This resets the choice back to 'Please select'

```
resetForm: function() {     
      this.fee = "";      
    },


<button @click="resetForm" class="btn">
              Reset
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This small code samples don't give much informations but You may try calling Feeonchange function at the end of resetForm function, because the function Feeonchange is not aware that the value of this.fee have changed after You click Reset button.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt not think of that. You said 'calling Feeonchange function at the end of resetForm function'. How would I do that? Im quite new to Vue. Thanks

Comment: Again I don't know how Your code looks like. If this is one component You can call Feeonchange() in resetForm() like this:

resetForm( ...some code ... this.Feeonchange()) . Show Your whole component and we can think of a good solution because I don;t even know what is this : this.query(query); Is this another method or were You trying to change data value which should look like this this.query = query

Comment: I was thinking about this incorrectly. I was trying to reset the filters rather than trying to repopulate them. So in the end the solution was 

 resetForm() {
      this.search_input = "";
      this.fee = "";
      //clears the arrays back to their default state
      this.query("!showall");
    },

Easy when you know how!